# Spring @JpaDataTest no transaction

Tags: spring, spring-test

I'm tring to use @JpaDataTest to test my repository

I'm use it like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertEquals(0, myRepo.findAll().size());
        entityManager.persist(new MyEntity());
        //entityManager.flush();
        assertEquals(1, myRepo.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

Test doesn't pass because of the second findAll return 0 entity

If i remove the commentary to flush

i got an error

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Comment: Hi Alexandre.How do you run this test?Maven?

Comment: Hi, i run as Junit Test, if i use maven it failed too.

Yesterday i POC it with another class but i not saved it and everything works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find why...

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

if i remove @ComponentScan it works...